# why recyclerview lollipop load everything?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of 100 items. I'm using a recyclerview with custom adapter.

It seems that all the items are load in the same times which cause OOM because I'am loading big images.

I have no problem with listview because listview does not load everything at once.

I heard that recyclerview load everything at once on lollipop, but how can I fix that?

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductViewHolder> {
    List<Produit> list;
    private Context ac;
    private int nbColumn;

    public ProductAdapter(List<Produit> list, Context ac)
    {
        this.list = list;
        this.ac = ac;
        this.nbColumn = 2;
    }

    public ProductAdapter(List<Produit> list, Context ac, int nbColumn)
    {
        this.list = list;
        this.ac = ac;
        this.nbColumn = nbColumn;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int itemType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_product,viewGroup,false);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }


    public void setNbColumn(int nb)
    {
        this.nbColumn = nb;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {
        if (list != null) {
            System.out.println("LOAD ITEM!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            final Produit myObject = list.get(position);

            myViewHolder.bind(myObject);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

without start scrolling the output is

> I/System.out: LOAD ITEM!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

X100 times

UPDATE :

this is the code of my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is a title"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/list1_unselected"
                android:id="@+id/list1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cat"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/list2"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/list2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cat"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list1"
                android:clickable="true"
                />
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/listingGrid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:layout_below="@+id/list2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please format the code for indentation?

Comment: You probably need to resize the images

Comment: The code is indented now, thx.

Comment: @Roman Kolomenskii, you are probably right, but that does not explain why recyclerview load all items at once when a listview load only visible item (during the scroll)

Comment: what is the height of your views (R.layout.item_product)? and which LayoutManager are you using with the RecyclerView? please post the layout's xml also

Comment: Try adding `position` to your log message, I think same items are bound multiple times. Had that bug in the past.

Comment: @Massimo, I set the height at "wrap_content" and I'm using a GridLayoutManager

Comment: @Roman Kolomenski, After put a the position in my log, I see 1 to 100, it seems that same item was not bound multiple time, but thanks for the advice, I didn't think about that possibility

Comment: @wilfleaji ok, but how much high is this height? the fact that it loads all its adapter views at one time suggests me that all the views can be contained by your `RecyclerView`

Comment: is your RecyclerView under a layout (or have) with "weight" attribute?

Comment: Yeah actually, my Recyclerview does not fit all the parent view.

The Recyclerview is wrap by a NestedScrollView

Comment: This could exactly be your problem. Try to give a fixed height to the `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 1):

Set `android:layout_height` of your `RecyclerView` to `match_parent` or some constant value.

**EDIT:**

Obviously it didn't help, since you have it all wrapped in `NestedScrollView`.

I would suggest removing `NestedScrollView` and combining all views from your `RelativeLayout` into another layout that you would use as header in your `RecyclerView`

Comment: I tried, but I still have the problem.
I paste the code of my layout above. Thank you

Comment: I used NestedScrollview because in my view I need to display other stuff such as text, image etc.. if I remove NestedScrollView, it's not all of my view which will scroll but only the recycler view, and I don't really want that kind of behavior. 

But anyway your suggest is helpfull, I could find the source of the problem, in waiting to find what's wrong with NestedScrollView, I will remove it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I partially figured out my problem. After removing the NestedScrollView, the behavior of my Recyclerview works as expected. The thing is how can I combine both NestedScrollView and RecyclerView?

Thank you

Comment: did you finde the way to combine them ? please put the answer

Comment: No I didn't, actually in my case it was a design issue, the NestedScrollView was not needed. Sorry that I can't help more

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if (list != null)` with `if (myViewHolder != null)` and it will work as intended

Comment: Unfortunatly it does not work either. All items are loaded at once.